# BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default (React JS, TypeScript & JWT)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jwt, react-typescript

When I want to verify the jwt token in React with TypeScript, it gives this error, how to solve it?

`

```js
const [decodedToken, setDecodedToken] = useState<null | JwtPayload | string>(null);
```

```js
  const verifyToken = (token: string) => {
    try {
      // Decode the token
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, `${process.env.REACT_APP_JWT_SECRET}`);

      // Check if the token is valid
      if (decoded) {
        return decoded;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      // Return null if the token is invalid
      return null;
    }
  };
```

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const localToken = localStorage.getItem(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_APPLICATION_NAME}-auth`
    );

    if (localToken) {
      const token = JSON.parse(localToken);
      const decoded = verifyToken(token.token);

      if (decoded) {
        // The token is valid, set the decoded token in state
        setDecodedToken(decoded);
      } else {
        // The token is invalid, redirect the user to the login page
      }
    }
  }, []);
```

`

> Compiled with problems:X
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/buffer-equal-constant-time/index.js 4:13-37
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in '/home/hossain/Documents/projects/travel-hunter/client/node_modules/buffer-equal-constant-time'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
> install 'buffer'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js 18:4-21
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/hossain/Documents/projects/travel-hunter/client/node_modules/jsonwebtoken'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
> install 'crypto-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

I have tried many solutions in [github](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11756#issuecomment-1001162736), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70398678/i-tried-to-polyfill-modules-in-webpack-5-but-not-working-reactjs), but can't solve it!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I do not think you are able to solve this problem with the 'jsonwebtoken' package. However, you can verify your token using a package called [jwt_decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode). You can begin by decoding your token, then logging it into the console.

```js
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
const decoded = jwt_decode(token)
console.log(decoded)
```

You will then know the type of data being received when the token is verified. You can then use this to create a helper function to serialize the data to the desired format.

```js
export function deleteProps (obj: unserializedData, props: string[]) {
  for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
     if (obj.hasOwnProperty(props[i])) {
      // @ts-ignore
      delete obj[props[i]];
     }
  }    

  return obj 
}
```

The object return will now be of the required data type and you will be able to update your react state.

```js
const serializedUser = deleteProps(decoded, ['_v','exp','iat'])
setDecodedToken(serializedUser)
```

For more information on the topic you can check this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855672/cant-use-jsonwebtoken-with-latest-version-of-react)